# How to extract a subset of a tbl_mysql or tbl_sqlite data frame by row numbers?

Tags: mysql, sql, r, sqlite, dplyr

As I understand the help page of the slice function of the dplyr package, one can select the rows of an SQL tbl or an SQLite tbl like this:

```
filter(mtcars, row_number() == 1L)
```

However I get an error when I try:

```
dat1 <- data.frame(
  Name = c("Joe", "Bill", "Jim", "Kate"),
  Value = c(10.1, 9, 7.7, -3),
  Indic = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 2L),
  Status = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)
)
#### Create SQLite database ####
library(dplyr)
my_database <- src_sqlite("db_sqlite_file", create = TRUE) 
#### Put data in database ####
copy_to(my_database, dat1, temporary = FALSE)
#### Connect to database ####
my_db <- src_sqlite("db_sqlite_file", create = FALSE)
#### Querying the database ####
dd <- tbl(my_db, "dat1")
ddextract <- filter(dd, row_number() == 1L)
```

The error message occurs here:

```
> ddextract  
Source: sqlite 3.8.6 [db_sqlite_file]
Error in sqliteSendQuery(con, statement, bind.data) : 
  error in statement: no such function: ROW_NUMBER
```

The same problem with MySQL:

```
my_db_sql <- src_mysql("mysql_dplyr", password="mypassword") 
dd <- tbl(my_db_sql, "dat1")
ddextract <- filter(dd, row_number() == 1L)
```

The error:

```
> ddextract
Source: mysql 5.5.49-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 [root@localhost:/mysql_dplyr]
Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : 
  could not run statement: FUNCTION mysql_dplyr.ROW_NUMBER does not exist
```

Of course I could create a new column with the row numbers, but I'm wondering why `filter(mtcars, row_number() == 1L)` does not work.

Comment: did you try `dplyr::filter()` ?

Comment: This is `dplyr::filter`.

Comment: you can also have a look to `dplyr::slice`

Comment: @Bakalegum From the help page : "Slice does not work with relational databases because they have no intrinsic notion of row order. If you want to perform the equivalent operation, use filter() and row_number()."

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
ddextract <- dd %>% collect() %>% filter(row_number() == 1L)
```

Comment: thanks, but if one does `collect` then the `tbl_sqlite` class is lost.

Comment: But that's not a bad idea. After doing `collect` one can treat the data frame as a usual `tbl` and then copy it back to the database (using `copy_to`).

Comment: mmhhh... finally no it is not a good way to that, because I don't want to copy it to the database, because it's not the "final" data frame. Anyway that does not really solves the problem, but it's a possible way to go.